# Angular HttpErrorResponse

Tags: angular

I am trying to get user cart by sending username on request URL, but I am getting an error.

```
list: PanieDto[] = [];
@Input() listform: PanieDto = new PanieDto();
isLoggedIn = false;
showAdminBoard = false;
showModeratorBoard = false;
private roles: string[] = [];
PanieDocument?: string[] = [];
username?: string;

constructor(private router: Router, private panieService: PanieService, private tokenStorageService: TokenStorageService) {
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.isLoggedIn = !!this.tokenStorageService.getToken();
    this.Productlist(this.username);

    if (this.isLoggedIn) {
        const user = this.tokenStorageService.getUser();
        this.roles = user.roles;

        this.showAdminBoard = this.roles.includes('ROLE_ADMIN');
        this.showModeratorBoard = this.roles.includes('ROLE_MODERATOR');
        this.username = user.username;
    
    }
}

Productlist(username: string | undefined): void {
    this.panieService.getlist(username).subscribe(result => {
        this.list = result;
    });
}
```

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
}

getlist(username: string | undefined): Observable<PanieDto[]> {
    return this.http.get<PanieDto[]>(SHOP_API + 'panie' + username);
}
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: The **username** you are sending is `undefined`, See the URL in the error, you are invoking `this.Productlist` before assigning username

Comment: i did assigning username before this.Productlist But it still same error

Comment: thanks anyway, I found out that I had made a lot of mistakes even in the backend probably because I am tired

Comment: what do you have on port 8080? Basically is your app on port 8080 up and running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am are invoking this.Productlist before assigning username